# Merging arrays with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here is my array:

```
array(
    'username' => 'Username cannot be empty',
    'password' => 'Password cannot be empty',
    '_external' => array(
        'email' => 'Email cannot be empty',
    ),
),
```

... and I want to get this result from my array:

```
array(
    'username' => 'Username cannot be empty',
    'password' => 'Password cannot be empty',
    'email' => 'Email cannot be empty',
),
```

I know how to do this with `foreach` loop, but it's too big code. Is there any short and fast method to do this?

Comment: @yes123: I assume, he wants to flatten the multidimensional array into a flat one, but thats just my assumption. What I don't understand: What do you (@foreachLoop) mean with "but it's to big code"? I guess, it will be not more than (lets say) 10 lines or such using `foreach`.

Comment: @king: yes before your formatting i didn't notice the nested

Comment: DOH you changed it @loop anyway my solution doens't need changes

Comment: I found answer, thanks for very fast response :)

Comment: pick one http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array+flatten+php

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
  if (is_array($array[$k])) {
   $array = array_merge($array,$array[$k]);
   unset($array[$k]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
  $value = $array[$key];
  if (is_array($value)) {
    unset($array[$key]);
    $array = array_merge($array, $value);
  }
}
```

After the edit of the question its much simpler

```
$x = $array['_external'];
unset($array['_external']);
$array = array_merge($array, $x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Less verbose:

```
$tmp_obj = (object) array('flatten' => array());  
array_walk_recursive($my_multidim_array, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->flatten[] = $v;'), $tmp_obj);

var_dump($tmp_obj->flatten);
```

Comment: less verbose but nearly not-understandable :D

Comment: That's all relative I suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
array_splice($array, 2, 1, $array[2]);
```